# I need compare two datetime in symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony, datetime, compare

i need to compare two DateTime in symfony 2.8, for that i have the nexts line's code in my controller where Prestamo it is an entity:

```
$FD = $Prestamo->getDate();
$DA = new \DateTime("now");
if(var_dump($DA > $FD)){
  $Prestamo->getUser()->setSomething("Mul");
  $em->flush();
}
```

but does not works! Please, i need it and the documentation i have seen does not works me

since now, Thank you very much

Comment: First, are you sure that `$Prestamo->getDate()` returns DateTime Object?
And remove var_dump() function in your condition.

Comment: Yes, i am too sure.

Comment: It seems you have a Typo too: `$FA` doesn't exist. Try `if ($DA > $FD) { ... }`

Comment: excuse me, it was my wrong, but in my code it is right, like you told me.

Comment: Amazing, it is works!!!!!! i just going to share my solution.

Comment: But the solution is identical at the code in the question o-O!?

Comment: Why would you do a `$em->flush()` without a persist first???

Answer (score 0):

I just had to make little changes, thanks to @scoolnico for his answer  I could do it

```
$FD = $Prestamo->getDate();
$DA = new \DateTime("now");
if ($DA > $FD) {
    $Prestamo->getUser()->setsomething("Mul");
    $em->flush();
}
```

Thank you very much